# Set custom path for ubuntu to understand php is installed

Tags: 14.04, php, configuration, versions

I have installed Ampps on my ubuntu and it's working great and has awesome features but my problem is that when I want to work with php in terminal or my IDE terminal it give me this error message :

```
The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

I'm currently avoiding this issue by typing :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/ampps/php/bin:$PATH
```

in that particular terminal and this method will work for only a single terminal window and it's very annoying to type it every time.

Is there a way to include this path in somewhere which ubuntu understand that my php is installed and it's in `/usr/local/ampps/php/bin` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put that line in your rc file. If you use `bash`, that file would be `~/.bashrc`. Every line in that file will be executed when you open a terminal. Just put it in, save the file, and open a new terminal. Now you should be able to use `php` in terminal without typing anything.